# JQuery - Error with UI and Animations

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I get this specific error when working with jquery ui datepicker and have also had the same error when using toggle("slow")

ERROR

jQuery.speed is not a function

Anyone any ideas why this may occur

FF3 / Firebug

Thanks
Shaun

Comment: Using jquery from google api 
Document ready is $('document').ready(function(){
 $('body').stateSwitcher();
 $("#slidingPanel").slideOut();
 $("#startdate").datepicker();
 $("#enddate").datepicker();
});

Comment: Script tags are <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Maybe try clearing your browser's cache or trying another browser and see if you get the same problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version was OK appeared to be plugin conflict.

Answer (score 1):

I'd check to make sure that the version of jQuery you are including is compatible with the version(s) of the datepicker/jQuery UI you are also using.

Comment: Same versions as on jqueryui website where it works fine?
Strange

Comment: NOW that is !! jquery 1.3.2 ui 1.7.1